# Initializing a pointer at declaration time in a C struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

Is there a way to initialize a pointer in a C struct at declaration time:

```
struct person
{
  uint8_t age;
  uint16_t * datablock;
} mike = { 2, malloc(4) };
```

I've tried the code above, but I get:

> initializer element is not constant for the datablock member.

I'm using GCC.

Comment: you are calling the function `malloc()`, but the initializator must be compile-time constant.

Comment: File scope initializers must consist of constants.

Comment: Does code need to later change `mike.datablock` to point allocated memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How to initialize a struct's member at declaration

You can initialize the members of the struct at its declaration by means of a *compile-time constant* as in the code below:

```
struct person
{
  uint8_t age;
  uint16_t * datablock;
} mike = { 2, NULL };
```

---

#### Why does your code not compile?

`malloc(4)` is, however, a *function call* and it will be performed at *run-time*. Therefore, the error message you are getting is quite accurate indeed.

---

#### Alternative to run-time allocation

You could however do something like this:

```
#define NUM 2 // change NUM at will
static uint16_t data[NUM]; // memory that will be allocated

struct person
{
  uint8_t age;
  uint16_t * datablock;
} mike = { 2, data };
```

Note that, in this case, the address of `data` is known at compile time, so you can use it as an initializer for the struct's members.

Comment: I see, thank you. However at compile time i'm allocating 8 bits to hold the age value. How do i do this for a custom type with a custom size?

Comment: @moonraker by changing `NUM` in the code above you can customize the size to be allocated.